# jquery returns undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code on my header for creating som pop up

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Lorsque vous cliquez sur un lien de la classe poplight et que le href commence par #
    $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
        var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Trouver la pop-up correspondante
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Retrouver la largeur dans le href

        //Récupérer les variables depuis le lien
        var query= popURL.split('?');
        var dim= query[1].split('&amp;');
        var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //La première valeur du lien

        //Faire apparaitre la pop-up et ajouter le bouton de fermeture
        $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({
            'width': Number(popWidth)
        })
            .prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Fermer" alt="Fermer" /></a>');

        //Récupération du margin, qui permettra de centrer la fenêtre - on ajuste de 80px en conformité avec le CSS
        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

        //On affecte le margin
        $('#' + popID).css({
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        //Effet fade-in du fond opaque
        $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Ajout du fond opaque noir
        //Apparition du fond - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) pour corriger les bogues de IE
        $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn();

        return false;
    });

    //Fermeture de la pop-up et du fond
    $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //Au clic sur le bouton ou sur le calque...
        $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //...ils disparaissent ensemble
        });
        return false;
    });    
});
```

I use also jquery on the head of my document

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

the trouble is that it return to me an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

exactly on the part where I shpould click for closing the popup

so I can open it but not close it.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in 1.9. You need to use `.on()` instead

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.close, #fade', function() { //Au clic sur le bouton ou sur le calque...
    $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //...ils disparaissent ensemble
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`live` is removed from jQuery 1.9, and you are using jQuery 1.10.2 => Error.

You can use **on()** to handle or use **delegate** to use Event Delegation.

Using **bind**, **click** to handle event directly.

**on**

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a.close, #fade', function() { //Au clic sur le bouton ou sur le calque...

});
```

**delegate**

```
 $(document).delegate('a.close, #fade','click', function() { //Au clic sur le bouton ou sur le calque...

   });
```

**click**

```
 $('a.close, #fade').click(function(){});
```

**bind**

```
$('a.close, #fade').bind("click",function(){});
```

Hope it'll help you.